# converting object to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to convert object to array of objects in javascript.
how to convert object `result` to array of objects

```
function arrobj(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key=>obj[key]);
}

var result = {
    name: "sample",
    size: "12",
    country: "SG"
}
```

Expected Output

```
result=[
  {
    name: "sample",
    size: "12",
    country: "SG"
  }
]
```

Comment: `[ result ]` ..?

Comment: All you need to do is wrap the object in an array: `let arrobj = (o) => [o];`

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it inside an array,

```js
var result = {
    name: "sample",
    size: "12",
    country: "SG"
};

result = [result];
console.log(result)
```